# Are can openers like the original Swing-A-Way sold under a different name now?

Tags: equipment

Swing-A-Way can openers used to be made in St. Louis, MO. After the family sold out they finally ended up being made in China. The quality went away. I thought I came across some info that the possibly former St. Louis factory/equipment was acquired by someone else and that a new company was making can openers with the same quality again but I can not document this now. Is that true? Is there another brand name selling them now?

Comment: And I guess the question is "Does anyone know where the equipment went?"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps: http://www.ez-duz-it.com

St Louis, claims to be only one made in USA, Seems to fit time-wise.

per one of several catalog sites (http://www.sierravalleytrading.com/JOHN-J-STEUBY-CO_c_815.html)

*John J Steuby Company
of Hazelwood, Missouri, has purchased the equipment used to manufacture the original,
MADE IN USA, SWING-A-WAY 
can opener and now uses that equipment to manufacture the
EZ-DUZ-IT
can opener.*

Comment: Seems like „this domain is for sale“ - with a load of Chinese text.

Comment: 7 years later I don't find that terribly shocking...